# Find a general formula for the recursion formula.

Tags: calculus

If $a_1=1$,$$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+3}{a_n+1}$$ 
Find $a_n$.

---

I attempted to use the method of  'coefficient ' like assume $a_{n}=k\cdot d^n$ or $a_n= c \cdot n +d$. But after some calculation they all failed.

Comment: Where does this problem come from?  Is there any reason to believe it has a closed-form solution?

Comment: Papa [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a_(n%2B1)%3D(a_n%5E2%2B3)%2F(a_(n)%2B1),+a_1%3D1) doesn't found solution

Comment: Are you perhaps trying to show $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=3?$  Finding an explicit formula isn't the right approach.

Comment: @ saulspatz  Sorry I don't know the meaning of ' closed form'. It is a question from my brother's high school competition exercise. Also are you intending to do the way of claiming it has no general formula. Are there possible ways to proof that ?

Comment: "Closed form" means the same thing as "general formula."  I'm not making any claims, but I'd be very surprised if there is a general formula.  For example, $a_11$ is a fraction with $210$ digits in both the numerator and the denominator, and I would expect the number of digit to double at most, if not all iterations.   As for a proof, that kind of thing is generally very difficult.  Is this the **entire** question from the competition?  If so, I'm amazed.